# CAML Query BeginsWith Numeric Issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, caml

In the following CAML query I reference 0 in the the line below.

```
<Value Type='Text'>0</Value>
```

This doesn't work even when the value is 0 bu twhen it is A it does work (I have entries in for both A and 0).  I am unsure why numeric values are not getting picked up.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<Query>
      <Where>
        <And>
          <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='TCategories' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Abbreviations</Value>
          </Eq>
          <BeginsWith>
            <FieldRef Name='FirstCharacter' />
            <Value Type='Text'>0</Value>
          </BeginsWith>
        </And>
      </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i do have a similar query like this

[image]
which is actually working fine for me.

Make sure that the columns in your query "TCategories" and "FirstCharacter" are of Text type.

Thanks,
-Codename "Santosh"